# I cannot see the icons from django-sitetree

Tags: django-sites

[image: sitetree menu icons]

I cannot see the icons from admin/sitetree..

must be a url problem.. I cannot figure out.

I need some help please.

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to be discussed and fixed in https://github.com/idlesign/django-sitetree/issues/122. Version with the fix is yet to come.

Comment: looks like in template  {{ STATIC_URL }} is empty. where should I add this to fix it?

Comment: @Young You can either fetch the latest sources from the repository, or wait for the next release (presumably in a week).

Comment: I have a same problem, cannot find solution so far

Comment: yes, you are right. it is fixed. .. @user .. just do uninstall and install django-sitetree will fix it. [ at least it worked for me now ]